# What does padColor(:,:,1) mean in MatLab?

Tags: matlab, syntax

```
>> padColor = [1 1 1];        %# RGB triple for pad color
padColor = reshape(padColor,1,1,3);  
>> padColor

padColor(:,:,1) =

     1


padColor(:,:,2) =

     1


padColor(:,:,3) =

     1
```

What does `padColor(:,:,1)` mean here?

Answer (score 2):

After reshaping, `padColor` is a 1-by-1-by-3 array. Since the size of the first two dimensions is 1, `padColor(:,:,1)`, which means padColor("all","all",1) is equivalent to `padColor(1,1,1)`. In other words, `padColor(:,:,1)` is the element you find in the first row, first column, first 'z-slice' of padArray.

Comment: How can a 1-1-1 array be reshaped into a 1-1-3 array?Or more generally,into a m-n-k array?

Comment: Your original array is not 1-by-1-by-1; it's 1-by-3.